# HDR Metadata Tag for MacOS TV App / Apple TV

Tags: macos, ffmpeg, metadata, mp4, hdr

When importing Media in the MacOS TV App there have to be certain Tags in the Metadata of the Mp4/M4v file so that TV registers it as 4K. I want to have imported Movies with HDR10, HDR10+ or Dolby Vision be displayed as such, furthermore i hope that setting this Tag will also enable proper HDR playback in the App (I currently have to use a separate Video Player for imported HDR movies).

When i first tried to figure out how to set the HD and 4K tag I used ffprobe to look at digitally bough movies that were m4v files, for example "The Thing" gives the result:

```
Metadata:
major_brand     : M4V
minor_version   : 0
compatible_brands: M4V mp42isom
creation_time   : 2016-01-08T09:18:48.000000Z
title           : Das Ding aus einer anderen Welt
artist          : John Carpenter
genre           : Horror
compilation     : 0
date            : 1982-01-01T08:00:00Z
copyright       : © 1982 Universal City Studios Inc. All Rights Reserved.
description     : Im Winter 1982 entdeckt ein zwölfköpfiges Wissenschaftlerteam in einer entlegenen Forschungsstation am Südpol einen Außerirdischen, der über 100.000 Jahre im Schnee begraben war. Als er aufgetaut ist, tritt der Alien in immer wieder neuer Gestalt auf
hd_video        : 2
media_type      : 9
purchase_date   : 2022-09-13 19:00:14
sort_name       : Das Ding aus einer anderen Welt
sort_artist     : John Carpenter
iTunEXTC        : de-movie|Ab 16 Jahren|500|
```

The Tag "hd_video" determines what the TV app classifies the resolution of the Movie as:

| hd_Video Value | Resolution |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 480p |
| 1 | 720p |
| 2 | 1080p |
| 3 | 4K |

I'd try the same for HDR movies however the only HDR movies I bought digitally come in the HLS format which I don't know how to look into with ffprobe.
Any help with what Tags I need to set or how I can investigate the HLS format is much appreciated.